# classloading in WildFly

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly, xerces

Consider following structure of `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` inside `META-INF` of ear

```
<!-- Make sub deployments not isolated so they can see each others classes without a Class-Path entry (default is true) -->  
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>  

<deployment>  
    <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->  
    <exclusions>  
        <module name="org.apache.xerces" />  
    </exclusions>  
</deployment>  

<sub-deployment name="mySubDeployment.war">  
    <exclusions>  
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />  
    </exclusions>  
    <dependencies>  
        <system>  
            <paths>  
                <path name="com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom"/>  
                <path name="com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni"/>  
                <path name="com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/jaxp"/>  
            </paths>  
        </system>  
    </dependencies>  
</sub-deployment>
```

Given that, I have excluded default `org.apache.xerces` module from deployment (line#11) and deployed custom `xercesImpl.jar` in `APP-INF/lib` folder or ear. Also I have added path dependencies for `mySubDeployment.war` sub-deployment.

From where classes of xerces will be loaded for `mySubDeployment.war`? From the default `com.apache.xerces` module of WildFly or custom jar deployed in `APP-INF/lib`?

What is the exact meaning of adding path dependencies in sub-deployment? Will that ignore the exclusions (i.e. org.apache.xerces here) under main deployment?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really need those paths. You'll also have to exclude xerces for each [sub-deployment](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly#ClassLoadinginWildFly-JBossDeploymentStructureFile).

Also the `APP-INF` directory is not a standard Java EE directory. You'll need to put libraries in the `/lib` directory of your EAR.

Comment: 1. `The APP-INF directory is not a standard Java EE directory` - I don't think so !!
2. I need to exclude xerces for each sub-deployment. Does that mean config for deployment are implicitly not applied to sub-deployments?

Comment: `APP-INF` is not a Java EE standard, it's a WebLogic thing. That is correct, you need to explicitly exclude modules from each sub-deployment you don't want them to be a part of.

Comment: @james-r-perkins One more query, what if I mention `org.apache.xerces` in exclusions and also add path dependency of `<path name="com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/jaxp"/>`? Will this load classes inside `org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp` from `org.apache.xerces` module or custom jar I deploy in  APP-INF/lib ?

Comment: I'm not too sure what would happen honestly. FWIW anything in the `APP-INF/lib` directory will NOT be loaded at all.